# Silverlight Example Browser for OxyPlot

Tags: oxyplot

Where i can find the Silverlight Example Browser for oxyplot library. earlier on codeplex it was there but not working now. current link http://www.oxyplot.org/examplebrowser not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objorke commented on 7 Feb:

> I think the Silverlight example browser is still online, but is not updated any more.  I will delete it soon.

So it is deleted now I think.

Also you can download source code, build it and run example browser locally.

Source: https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/issues/763